# jQuery not Working on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/AH4As/3/

It works in the fiddle, but on my site, it does not. I'm getting this error in Web Inspector

```
Tracking.js:4TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$('a').attr('onClick').replace')
```

Does anybody know what wrong?

Here's my source code: http://jsfiddle.net/AH4As/24/

Comment: Check your source to make sure that jQuery is actually being loaded onto the site.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to guess? you've posted no code with the problem. If it works in the fiddle, then the problem is some other code.

Comment: @SOliver jQuery is definitely being loaded onto the site

Comment: @Scott What kind of source code can make the web inspector return an error?

Comment: It could be anything... a stray ' or " or a missing $ or a space where it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Scott Then it would return an error on both sites?

Comment: not if the error exists immediately before that line of code. Similar to how PHP errors are thrown at times, often it's the line below that throws the error due to a mistake in the line above it.

Comment: @Scott The file is being referenced in the `<head>`, there is no line of code before it, since it's its own file...

Comment: Well.. like I posted.. it's anyone's guess since no one but you sees the appropriate code.

Comment: @Scott Its a long source code

Comment: Plz show us Teh Codez - relevant codez will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other anchors on the page made the Query fail, in a nutshell this was my solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[onclick^="window.open(\'TrackPackage.asp"]').attr('onClick', $('a[onclick^="window.open(\'TrackPackage.asp"]').attr('onClick').replace("window.open('", "window.open('http://eastcoasttvs.com/"));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').attr('onClick', $('a').attr('onClick').replace("window.open('", "window.open('http://example.com/"));
});

​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AH4As/10/

And here it is with an alert to show you the code has been changed:
http://jsfiddle.net/AH4As/11/

Comment: Could there be a quotation issue?

Comment: Crack open the actual source code of the page (IE: VIEW SOURCE). Copy the jQuery call that's being injected and paste it into your original question. It's freaking ridiculous to ask people to fix your code when you don't show the code that's broken.

Comment: (and don't update it as an **answer** update it in your original question)

Comment: @Scott they're definitely not

Comment: `href="//ajax.googleapis.com` sure looks busted to me. And sorry.. comment was meant for the question.. not this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('a').removeAttr('onclick').click(function(){window.open('http://example.com');return false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').removeAttr('onclick');
    $('a').click(function(){
        window.open('http://www.example.com', '','location=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=1,width=635,height=460');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to (reliably) `replace` on the `onclick` with jQuery 1.4:

```
'function' === typeof $('a').attr('onclick');
```

And Functions don't have `replace` methods:

```
'undefined' === typeof $('a').attr('onclick').replace;
```

You're getting a function because jQuery is returning the **property** value rather than the **attribute** value.

The confusion from this is why jQuery added the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method in 1.6 -- so it's clear that you want the attribute value, not the property value:

```
// with jQuery 1.6+
'string' === typeof $('a').attr('onclick');
```

Now, if you're not able to update jQuery currently, you can try inserting a `toString` before the `replace`:

```
$('a').attr('onclick').toString().replace(...)
```

---

On a side-note: for better coupling of the original and adjusted value, you may look at using an alternate syntax for [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2):

```
$('a').attr('onclick', function (i, value) {
    return value.toString().replace('window.open(\'', 'window.open(\'http://example.com/'));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately updating jQuery isn't on the table… :( what do you mean by `toString`?

Comment: @user1090389 I mean it like I posted in the last code snippet -- call `.toString()` before calling `.replace(...)`.